# A curve lies locally on both sides only of the osculating plane.

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $\kappa \tau \neq 0$ at $P$. Of all the planes containing the tangent line to $\alpha$ at $P$, show that $\alpha$ lies locally on both sides only of the osculating plane.[image]

Comment: So neither $\kappa$ nor $\tau$ is a specific vector, and then  further that $\alpha$ lies locally on "both sides only" of the oscullating plane. To me it seems unclear geometrically what that means, Could you insert a few words about that, or maybe a diagram? Thanks.

Comment: This Question is taken from an article, as you can see the pic

Comment: @coffeemath: What you wrote makes no sense. $\kappa$ and $\tau$ are scalars.  Since this comes from my text, let me ask abdullah. Don't just post homework exercises. What have you tried? What is in the text that might be relevant?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I was confused in what I asked, I agree it makes no sense. I'll leave the comment as is, especially since now I can try (later) to follow the quoted part of article.

Comment: @coffeemath: We consider all planes passing through $P$ that contain the tangent line to $\alpha$ at $P$. With the exception of the osculating plane, in a small enough neighborhood of $P$, $\alpha$ lies only on one side of the plane. But with the osculating plane, it crosses from one side to the other at $P$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, Ted. I 'm starting to see it intuitively...